# How to detect that a retention policy has deleted unprocessed consumer data from the hdd?

Tags: apache-kafka

How to detect that a retention policy has deleted unprocessed consumer data from the hdd ?

I've found only one solution, it is set consumer setting `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG="none"`.
If retention policy has deleted unprocessed consumer data then consumer throws `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException` exception.

Is it right solution ?
Is exist better solution ?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable solution to me if you want to detect it from a consumer